# "Launch Screen.storyboard" black after adding png

Tags: ios, storyboard, launch-screen

Adding "Launch Screen.storyboard" works fine with the default white background, I get my logo and copyright, then move to Main.storyboard, all is good, app works fine.  Adding "Image View" to launch is also okay, but when I add the png in Media.xcassets to "Image View" the screen turns all black before moving on to Main.  If I clear the png name from Image View/Image it all works, but goes back to the white background at launch time.  A darker version (so white text can be seen) of the same png serves as the background for Main.storyboard and that is fine. What's the trick to get the launch screen png to show up in its view?  Xcode 12.4, deployment 12.0. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to make your launch screen "small" enough (whatever that means) to be accepted.  I solved the problem by simply taking a screen shot of the failing png, producing a new png that had smaller x/y dimensions and was about one third the original size (4.9 MB instead of 13.2 MB).  It looks the same to me.  (The failing png worked fine in main.storyboard.)